# How to map keys to functions with different arguments?

Tags: stdmap, std-function

Is there a simple way to map keys to functions with variable number of arguments (and possible varible return type?). This is what I mean.

```
//three functions, each variable number of args
void one_arg(int a) { std::cout << "a"; }
void two_args(int a, double b) { std::cout << "a\t" << "b\n"; }
void three_args(int a, double b, const char* c) { std::cout << "a\t" << "b\t" << "c\n"; }

std::function<void(int)> f_onearg = one_arg;
std::function<void(int, double)> f_twoargs = two_args;
std::function<void(int, double, const char*)> f_threeargs = three_args;

//now what??
template<typename... Args>
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(Args...)>> map_of_fun{ {"one", one_arg }, {"two", two_args}, {"three",three_args} };

//this is how i would like to call it
map_of_fun["one"](4);
map_of_fun["two"](4, 9.34);
```

What am I doing wrong? It doesnt work, the mistake is somewhere in the template, but I dont know where.

Answer (score 0):

ok, problem solved with std::bind

```
std::function<void()> f_onearg = std::bind(one_arg, 10);
std::function<void()> f_twoargs = std::bind(two_args, 10, 3.14);
std::function<void()> f_threeargs = std::bind(three_args, 10, 3.14, "helo");


std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> map_of_func{ {"one", f_onearg}, {"two", f_twoargs}, {"three", f_threeargs} };
map_of_func["one"]();
map_of_func["two"]();   
map_of_func["three"]();
```